# Why aren't my values being initialized by my initialization (parameterized) constructors?

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, initialization

I have a base class `Point` with 3 variables I want derived as `Body` attributes. I want to initialize a point and use it to initialize a body object. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
    public:
        double x, y, z;

        // default constructor
        Point(): x(0), y(0), z(0){
        };
        // intialization constructor
        Point(double x, double y, double z){
            x = x;
            y = y;
            z = z;
        }
        // copy constructor
        Point(const Point &point){
            x = point.x;
            y = point.y;
            z = point.z;
        }

        void print_point(){
            cout << "x = "<< x << " y = " << y << " z = " << z << endl;
        }
};

class Body: public Point{
    public:
        double mass;

        // default constructor
        Body(): Point(0, 0, 0), mass(0){
        };
        // intialization constructor
        Body(const Point& point, double mass): Point(point.x, point.y, point.z){
            mass = mass;
        }
        // copy constructor
        Body(const Body &body): Point(body){
            mass = body.mass;
        }

        void print_body(){
            cout << "x = "<< x << " y = " << y << " z = " << z << " mass = " << mass << endl;
        }
};


int main() {

    Point p(1., 2., 3.);
    p.print_point();

    Body b(p, 65.);
    b.print_body();

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this, I get:

```
x = 0 y = 0 z = 6.95312e-310
x = 2.25081e-314 y = 0 z = 0 mass = 0
```

When I am expecting to get:

```
x = 1 y = 2 z = 3
x = 1 y = 2 z = 3 mass = 65
```

It's like the variables are being reset by the default constructors, and I don't know what's causing this.

Comment: `mass = mass` needs to be `this->mass = mass`.

Comment: What do you think `x=x` does and why? *Always use member initialisation syntax*. Never assign members in the body of the constructor. Make it automatic. Writing a constructor? Type a colon *immediately*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change the assignment inside the constructor body from

```
x = x;
y = y;
z = z;
```

to

```
this->x = x;
this->y = y;
this->z = z;
```

Inside the constructor's body, the parameter's name *hides* the data member's name. e.g. `x = x;` just assigns the parameter `x` to itself, doesn't assign the data member `x`. The class `Body` has the same issue.

The better way would be initializing the data members with [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), (btw it doesn't have such *name hiding* issue). e.g.

```
Point(double x, double y, double z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
```

Comment: And it's best to adopt a common suffix or prefix for private data members (like `x_`, `y_`, `z_`).

Comment: @NikosC. so like `Point(double x_, double y_, double z_) : x(x_), y(y_), z(z_) {}`?

Comment: @scrollout No, the other way around. The private members should have the `_` suffix. It's a common practice in languages that have classes. Some people use a `_` suffix, some people use a letter prefix (like `m_x`, `m_y`, `m_z`). It helps avoid having to write `this->`, and it also makes it clear that the object is a private data member without having to go look up the class definition. Of course here these members are public, but I assume that's just in your example code. They should be private and have public getter functions.